# PhpSpec expected call exact

Tags: unit-testing, phpspec, laravel-5

I have a method for my Laravel5 application I'm trying to test in PhpSpec but it keeps throwing the following error:

```
App/Helpers/RecurrRule                              
37  ! it should return a recurrence collection method call:
    Double\ChurchRepositoryInterface\P6->getChurchTimezone(1) was not expected.
    Expected calls are:
    - getChurchTimeZone(exact(1))
```

The method is passed an array, and I want to mock that the model's getChurchTimezone method returns a timezone.

Method:

```
public function __construct(Rule $rule, ArrayTransformer $arrayTransformer, ChurchRepositoryInterface $church)
{
    $this->rule = $rule;
    $this->arrayTransformer = $arrayTransformer;
    $this->church = $church;
}


public function getRecurrenceCollection($schedule)
{
    $timezone    = $this->church->getChurchTimezone($schedule['church_id']);
    // more code
}
```

In my other specs I'm frequently doing things like `$double->method('someArgument')->willReturn('blah')`, but for some reason this specific case isn't working and I'm baffled as to why.

I've tried giving it a copy of the array, I've tried giving it an integer directly, I tried pulling $this->church->getChurchTimezone into its own method and passing it an array or an integer, but no matter what PhpSpec invariably comes back with an 'exact' on the expected calls error.

Spec:

```
class RecurrRuleSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{

    protected $schedule = [
        'church_id' => 1,
        'start' => '2014-11-21 10:36:07',
        'end' => '2014-11-21 11:36:07',
        'recurr_rule' => 'FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=SU;',
        'recurr_until' => '2015-02-22 10:36:07',
    ];

    function it_is_initializable()
    {
        $this->shouldHaveType('App\Helpers\RecurrRule');
    }

    /**
     * Setup our mock, with doubles matching our constructor
     */
    function let($rule, $arrayTransformer, $church)
    {
        $rule->beADoubleOf('\Recurr\Rule');
        $arrayTransformer->beADoubleOf('\Recurr\Transformer\ArrayTransformer');
        $church->beADoubleOf('\App\Repositories\ChurchRepositoryInterface');

        $this->beConstructedWith($rule, $arrayTransformer, $church);
    }

    function it_should_return_a_recurrence_collection($rule, $arrayTransformer, $church)
    {
        $church->getChurchTimeZone(1)->willReturn('Europe/Dublin');
        // $church->getChurchTimeZone($this->schedule['church_id'])->willReturn('Europe/Dublin');
        // $church->getChurchTimeZone(Argument::any())->willReturn('Europe/Dublin');
        $rule->createFromString()->willReturn([]);
        $arrayTransformer->transform()->willReturn([]);


        $this->getRecurrenceCollection($this->schedule)->shouldReturn([]);
    }
```

Here's another example of a spec elsewhere in my app that uses the same approach and passes

```
function it_should_return_a_one_dimensional_numeric_array_of_servers($config)
{

    $expectedResult = ['domain.com', 'domain2.com'];

    $config->get('servers')->willReturn($this->configGetReturn);
    $this->serverArray()->shouldBeArray();
    $this->serverArray()->shouldEqual($expectedResult);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have spelled the method name differently in the spec and in the code:
getChurchTimeZone / getChurchTimezone

The clue really is in the error message:

```
getChurchTimezone(1) was not expected.

Expected calls are:
- getChurchTimeZone(exact(1))
```

By the way, you can take advantage of some of PhpSpec's magic by writing your let() function like this:

```
function let(Rule $rule, ArrayTransformer $arrayTransformer, ChurchRepositoryInterface $church)
{
    $this->beConstructedWith($rule, $arrayTransformer, $church);
}
```

PhpSpec automatically figures out the expected mocks from the typehints in the let() signature.